# get coordinates of viewable image area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a working fiddle of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/thindery/ZHhBR/

I need to be able to grab the coordinates of the source image's viewable area and display it in the span.

Here is an example of what I mean by display the coordinates of the viewable area: http://thindery.com/jsfiddle/crop_move.html

In this example, after you zoom in and pan around, you can see four different coordinates update like this: (x,y)(x1,y1)

Does jQuery provide this functionality so I can implement it in the jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could'nt really find a good way to get the coordinates from that plugin, so I just used a jQuery solution instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iv2 = $("#viewer2").iviewer({
        src: "http://thindery.com/jsfiddle/butterfly.jpg",
        onDrag: function() {
            var pos = $("img","#viewer2").position();
            $("#status").html('X : '+Math.abs(pos.left)+'<br>Y :'+Math.abs(pos.top));
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHhBR/9/)

Comment: i have one other question.  there should be two pairs of coordinates, so as to identify a rectangular shape.  how can I get the second pair?

Comment: The second set of coordinates look like they are just the first coordinates with the container size added, should'nt be a problem to figure out, something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHhBR/12/) ---

Comment: i thought the exact same thing.  but those second set of coordinates are not the first set with the container size added in.  the second set is based on the viewable pixels of the original image.  zooming the image in and out should change the second set of coordinates, because the second set is based on the original image width and height.

Comment: on this example: http://thindery.com/jsfiddle/crop_move.html if you zoom all the way out, you will see the coordinates are (0,0)(1024,438).  The original source butterfly image width is 1024 pixels.  the original height is 750.  So the first set of coordinates is where to start viewable area, and second set is where to end the viewable area. - all based on original image.